# How to return two ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issue trying to get response from ajax. However, if there is an issue it should return an error message and if there is no error, it should redirect:-
*The code below was only redirect even if there is an error and then is this the proper way to use post ajax request.*

**My code below:**

```js
$('input[data-post]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault;

    var ajaxRequest;
    var values = $('form').serialize();
    var output = $('div.message');

    ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        url: $('form').attr('action'),
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        data: values
    });

    ajaxRequest.done(function(){
        window.location.href = 'blah blah';
    });

    ajaxRequest.fail(function(){
        // output.html('error');
        console.log('error');

    }); 
});
```

Comment: `text/html` is not a valid content type for POST data.

Comment: `$('form').serialize()` returns `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. If you leave out `contentType`, that's the default.

Comment: `event.preventDefault;` should be `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.done()` runs no matter the result of the request. You're looking for `.success()` instead.

[Docs Reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: I tried making use of .success() but still get some javascript errors
TypeError: ajaxRequest.success is not a function

Comment: Try putting success directly in your ajax construction. `data: values, success: function() { ///}`